SSRS 2012 Old and New Values in a given table
I have gone all around the houses to try and find the right answer to this and desperately hoping someone can help. This is the query:
SELECT ev.LogicalName,
    CASE 
        WHEN au.Operation = 1 THEN 'Create' 
        WHEN au.Operation = 2 THEN 'Update' 
        WHEN au.Operation = 3 THEN 'Delete' 
        WHEN au.Operation = 4 THEN 'Access' 
    END AS Action, 
    FORMAT(DATEADD(mi, DATEDIFF(mi, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE()), au.CreatedOn), 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm') AS AuditCreated, 
    fr.rqia_registeredpersonidnumber AS RegisteredPerson, 
    au.AttributeMask
FROM [Audit] au
    INNER JOIN EntityView ev ON au.ObjectTypeCode = ev.ObjectTypeCode 
    INNER JOIN Filteredrqia_registeredperson fr ON au.ObjectId = fr.rqia_registeredpersonid
WHERE (ev.LogicalName = 'rqia_registeredperson') 
    AND (fr.rqia_registeredpersonidnumber = 'RP023523')
GROUP BY ev.LogicalName, 
            FORMAT(DATEADD(mi, DATEDIFF(mi, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE()), au.CreatedOn), 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm'), 
            au.Operation, 
            fr.rqia_registeredpersonidnumber, 
            au.AttributeMask
ORDER BY ev.LogicalName, AuditCreated

LogicalName is the name of the table in the database and RegisteredPerson is the ID of the service manager. All I would like to do is identify where changes have been made to a field called 'Status' in the LogicalName table and pull out the changes in the value. I have searched everywhere and cannot find an understandable solution. Is this really a complex thing to do?

Thanks for this - it is neater but still doesnt get me any further ahead re identifying changes in the actual 'Status' field

Is anybody able to assist with this?
